# Big Data Neophyte Trying To Work With FDA Data -- Any kind souls out there willing to help?

Tags: openfda

Question #1 -- We are trying the get the data currently in table form out of this online database and into a spreadsheet.  The end game is a postal mailing list/sales contact list.  So we're looking for first, last, title, company, addresses1, addresses2, city, state, zip/prov, country, phone, fax, email.  Any thoughts? https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cber/CFAppsPub/tiss/Index.cfm.

Question #2 -- Below is a link to a MAUDE report.  It’s a terrible incident involving a patient death.  Without sounding like I have a stone cold heart, I was more interested in other aspects of the report.  In the report there’s a data field called Manufacturer Contact.  Can I build a list of MAUDE Manufacturer Contact data quickly and easily? Same rational and end product as above:  first, last, title, company, addresses1, addresses2, city, state, zip/prov, country, phone, fax, email.  Any thoughts? 
http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/Cfdocs/cfmaude/detail.cfm?mdrfoi__id=3164029

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest filing a FOIA request with FDA for the complete dataset.

Barring that, web scraping is a common strategy for extracting data from web sites. It might be a stretch for a "neophyte," but it's something you'll find a ton of guidance on from a Google search. (Perhaps too much, but I think getting into the details of scraping are out-of-scope for this site, and definitely for this question.)

Note that a simple Google search for [how to scrape web pages](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS577US577&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20scrape%20web%20pages) includes a number of hits which talk about how to do it without writing your own code.

Answer (score 2):

to part two, you can scrape the document using google spreadsheets really easily, inserting `=ImportHTML("http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/Cfdocs/cfmaude/detail.cfm?mdrfoi__id=3164029", "table", 12)` into the first cell, where "12" denotes the table's number in the document. this isn't perfect, i already see two answers defined as table, so you'll want to probably hack around with it to see desired results.
also, there are a million better ways to do this, but figured this would be easiest for you.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IskCmIL16ur2urJdrAo7c_w_2AOIwsx_a1Kajvs1p5M/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

In answer to question #1, it looks like Excel Power Query can be used to bring the openFDA data into a table.

This video illustrates how to bring OpenFDA data into an Excel table. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-FhPq_0N0M